# losing image quality while converting base 64

Tags: ios, swift, base64, uiimage

[image: Please Check i have atteche]

I have one pdf and I am converting pdf to image and displaying in `UIImageView` and then after I am converting that image to base 64 but while converting base 64 I am losing the image quality so is there any way to prevent from losing quality while converting to base 64

please tell me is there any solution for that

here is my code for convert

```
let previewImage1 = convertedImageView.getImage()
let btnImg = UIButton()
btnImg.setImage(previewImage1, for: .normal)
let btn1Imggg2 = btnImg.image(for: .normal)
let imageData2 = btnImg?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)
let imgString2 = imageData2!.base64EncodedString(options: .init(rawValue: 0))
```

Even if i set compress quality to 0.0 still its compressing image

i have `UIView` Inside that i have `ScrollView` inside that i have `ImageView` and i am converting whole `UIView` as image and then convert into base64 the is the scenario hope this help you to understand

Code For `UIView` To `UIImage`

```
 func getImage(scale: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage {
        let newScale = scale ?? UIScreen.main.scale
        self.scale(by: newScale)

        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = newScale

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size, format: format)

        let image = renderer.image { rendererContext in
            self.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }

        return image
    }
```

Comment: “Even if i set compress quality to 0.0 still its compressing image” Yes, any jpeg is lossy, even with best quality.

Comment: 0.0 — most compression, worst quality; 1.0 — least compression Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata

Comment: i don't want to compress image just want to convert without compressing

Comment: Why not use `pngData()` (because it is lossless)? As stated above, jpg is a lossy format

Comment: i used `pngData()`  but i am getting low quality image

Comment: What is the size of the `btnImage`? Maybe it is not the conversion to `Data` but the source is the issue.

Comment: Also, you are getting image data from `UIButton` image property?  If you use the original image (`previewImage1`) is it better?

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman okay i think you are right let me try

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman i have tried with original image but still i am getting low quality image

Comment: Is the image in good quality to begin with? Based on your code I don't see any issues with conversion to `Data` (other than the compressionQuality). So I believe the issue is in the `UIImage` that you are trying to convert. Is there a way you can get the raw image and not derived from a UIView instance?

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman please check i have updated my question for your better understand

Comment: Please can you also show the code which you are using to convert the UIView as Image?

Comment: @VishalParmar, "i am converting whole UIView as image" — probably you should check for quality drop here instead

Comment: Please check i have updated code

Comment: i can't understand what you mean to say "i am converting whole UIView as image" probably you should check for quality drop here instead"

Answer (score 4):

By doing this

```
   let imageData2 = btnImg?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)
```

you are compressing the image with the maximum value possible. Change this code to

```
   let imageData2 = btnImg?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
```

and you will be good to go.

As you are converting the UIView to UIImage below function can be useful to you :

```
func image(with view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        view.layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return image
    }
    return nil
}
```

If the jpeg data does not suffice your requirement the user pngData like this

```
let imageData2 = btnImg?.pngData()
```

After getting the conversion to Image apply the base64 conversion as you are doing right now.

Comment: i tried this but still i am getting very low quality image

Comment: can you please tell me what is i replace 1.0 with 2.0 then which is the quality of image

Comment: According to this reference https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata for the best quality you have to put compression quality to 1.0

Comment: Okay Good but this can't help me to solve my problem

Comment: with your method i can't get solution

Comment: Can you try with pngData() as updated in my answer instead of jpegData...

Comment: i have tried with `pngData()` but same quality of image very low

Answer (score 2):

Okay, since you have a nested hierarchy (UIView -> UIScrollView -> UIImageView) and you wan't to capture that whole hierarchy as an image, it would be better to make an image from UIView (the topmost in the hierarchy, unless I understood wrong and you wan't the UIImageView part only)

```
let parentMostView = (the view you want to create into an image)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size: parentMostView.frame.size, NO, UIScreen.main.scale)

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGrapgicsEndImageContext()
let imageAsData = image.pngData()
//do your base64 conversion here
```

EDITED: Upon seeing your image creation code

I don't see any issues in your `getImage(:)` method. On what device are you testing(lower scale devices would create low resolution images because you are dependent on Device scale)? Try using a high static scale value(e.g 10) and replace Data conversion to `.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)` or `.pngData()`

Comment: Okay let me try and tell you whats the out put

Comment: I just saw your conversion code. Will check it for errors

Comment: i am trying on iPhone 6